# Datetime format in Ruby doesn't work for identifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord

I have a question about the format of **t.datetime.**

When I command in the rails console,

```
Lesson.find(1781).start_time,
```

then

`the Tue, 03 May 2016 14:00:00 UTC +00:00`

is returned.

If I command

```
Classtime.find_by(start_time: 'Tue, 03 May 2016 14:00:00 UTC +00:00')
```

, it returns nil.

But if I command

```
Classtime.find_by(start_time: Lesson.find(1781).start_time)
```

, it returns

```
<Classtime id: 4429, start_time: "2016-05-03 14:00:00", created_at: "2016-04-21 15:53:22", updated_at: "2016-04-21 15:53:22">
```

So I guess, `Lesson.find(1781).start_time` is not equal to the return of `Lesson.find(1781).start_time` in some sense. How would I be able to know what caused this?

Please share with me!!!

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
Classtime.find_by(start_time: Lesson.find(1781).start_time)
```

is the same as:

```
Classtime.find_by(start_time: '2016-05-03 14:00:00')
```

which is NOT the same as:

```
Classtime.find_by(start_time: 'Tue, 03 May 2016 14:00:00 UTC +00:00')
```

The database knows how to translate the string `2016-05-03 14:00:00` to a date, but not the string `Tue, 03 May 2016 14:00:00 UTC +00:00`.